# Ideal gas undergoing linear process on $V$-$T$ graph must be isobaric?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

> One mole of an ideal gas in initial state A undergoes a cyclic process ABCA, as shown in Fig. Its pressure at A is $P_0$. Choose the correct option(s) from the following.
>
> [image]
>
> (A) Internal energies at **A** and **B** are the same
>
> (B) Work done by the gas in process AB is $P_0 V_0 ln 4 $
>
> (C) Pressure at **C** is $P_0/4 $
>
> (D) Temperature at **C** is $T_0/4$

Question source: JEE advanced 2010

I have doubt only for option (C) and (D). You may attempt question with neutral mind before opening the spoilers.

> Official answer: (A),(B),(C),(D)

> My answer: (A),(B)

Method: There is no information of temperature or pressure at point **C**. From diagram information is revealed that process BC is linear but it may or may not be isobaric. So, we cannot conclude or comment anything about option **C** and **D**. Hence, they should not be ticked in exam. Is there any condition that process BC must be isobaric?

**In general: If the gas follows a line in V-T space, must the process be isobaric?**

Comment: Hi Jay: Definitely yes. Readability takes preference; searches are secondary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between proportionality and a more general straight line.  I get the equation for the line as $$V=V_0\left[1+3\frac{(T-T_C)}{(T_0-T_C)}\right]$$So, $$P=\frac{P_0(T/T_0)}{\left[1+3\frac{(T-T_C)}{(T_0-T_C)}\right]}$$The only way that P is the same at the two end points B and C is if $T_C=T_0/4$.  Mathematically, this will also guarantee that P is constant at all other points along the line.

Comment: Thanks Chet. You are right, I was going a little too quick with my answer. I have edited your answer to be less condescending though; I didn't really see the purpose in that :)

Answer (score 1):

For an ideal gas, the volume as a function of temperature is $V=\frac{Nk_B}{P}T$. Since process $BC$ follows a line in $V$-$T$ space, this means $Nk_B/P$ is constant. If the number of molecules in the gas is staying constant then this must be an isobaric process.

A more general treatment is given in [Chet's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/659534/179151). It looks like you have to assume the temperature at $C$ is $T_0/4$ in order for this to be isobaric. So it looks like either just choosing A and B is correct, or choosing all of them is correct as well.